# Can I use AWS PHP SDK to store S3 files locally?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We store files to S3. Every environment has it's own bucket and so every developer needs own bucket too.

I recently understood that rubygem AWS/S3 allows you to access local files via S3 interface. Local storage makes less network traffic, allows you to develop offline and is of course a bit cheaper.

Is there a similar way to do this in PHP?

There is a similar project called Fake S3 but judging from it's Github repository it's not actively maintained: https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3

Answer (score -1):

There's also this service: http://s3ninja.net/
But fake-s3 actually works fine with a few things to remember:

- no ssl support.
- it has some issues with the delete command.
- you might need to "tweak" your calls to S3 (when using fake-s3) with
  regards to the end point. example in aws-ios-sdk:

  ```
  // Create the S3 Client.
  AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithCredentials:uploadToken.credentials];
  // Create the amazon request.
  S3PutObjectRequest *request = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:uploadPath inBucket:uploadToken.container_name];

  if ([uploadToken.provider isEqualToString:@"fakes3"])
  {
      s3.endpoint = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost:9294/"];
      request.key = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", request.bucket, uploadPath];
      request.bucket = nil;
  }
  ```

Comment: The OP asks for a PHP solution. This looks like Objective C to me.

Comment: I gave a response regarding “Fake S3” and it’s more maintained alternative.